# Microsoft Teams Redirect URL to a Thread or Group Conversation

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I've been using the next URL to redirect any user to their private chat with our MS Teams App:

```
https://teams.microsoft.com/l/chat/0/0?users=28:b9cc7986-dd56-4b57-ab7d-9c4e5288b775
```

with `b9cc7986-dd56-4b57-ab7d-9c4e5288b775` being the App Id of our bot (*sample App Id in this case*).

This URL will open the private MS Teams Chat with the user clicking the URL and our App on any client (Mobile, Desktop, Browser) without opening any web pages if not needed. The clients can handle the URL themselves. You can try it with this provided sample URL.

**What would be a proper way to be able to redirect to a group conversation or thread**?

I've thought about using the Conversation Id (or other Ids available in our MS Teams App) or something but couldn't find any good documentation or examples online.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Deep Links to accomplish that, specifically [deep linking to a chat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links#deep-linking-to-a-chat). As shown in that link, you can link to specific users, but also set a conversation topic as well as an initial message. One thing that's often overlooked, just fyi, is this sentence:

> New chats are created in draft state until the user sends the first message

Comment: Yes I’ve seen that page too but I don’t think it is feasible in for example a group chat with over 100 users to add all users to the url? And the url being broken the second a user is removed/added?

Comment: that is a lot of users. If it's a regular group, maybe create a proper team rather, or keep the same link meeting on meeting. Alternatively, maybe create the chat in Graph, send an initial message, and then adding the users programmatically after that

Comment: @Jordy- Could you please confirm if your issue has resolved with above suggestion or still looking for any help?

Comment: Well, I can imagine the users of our bot could be in such big groups/teams/meetings so our bot has to support it. That is why I am not satisfied with providing all users to the url, because the url would also break if they add or remove users in the mean time. If there is an alternative using just the unique conversation ID, that would be way easier and more robust. So yes I am still looking for help. If I find the time I'll check if https://www.vrdmn.com/2021/11/building-microsoft-teams-bot-deep.html would maybe solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a message in the chat, click in the three dots for this message, create a task and copy the URL that is being generated.

The URL will redirect you to the respective message, what is useful to open the chat:

[image]

Comment: Might be a valuable answer, if would be able to construct that url on my own. Atm I'm not working on this project but if I would have to later on I will try this out and come back to this topic.